# How to make text centered in cell in openoffice spreadsheet?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

Is there anyway to make text centered in cell in openoffice spreadsheet? By center， I mean the same white space between left and right, top and bottom of the text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I got it "Format" -> "Cell"-> "Alignment" -> "Text alignment: Horizontal： Center", "Text alignment: Vertical: Middle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the sidebar, it can be done with only two clicks, circled in red below.

[image]

If you do not see the sidebar, then it can be expanded by clicking on the dots circled in green.  Make sure `View -> Sidebar` is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the help!